# Sync intent not triggered after account linkage with google assistant app

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I have created an actions SDK app which I can view in my google assistant. On clicking account linkage is complete with Auth2.0, but SYNC intent is not getting triggered and app just shows a message "Something went wrong".
My `action.json` :

```
{
    "actions": [{
      "name": "actions.devices",
      "fulfillment": {
        "conversationName": "automation"
      }
    }],
    "conversations": {
      "automation" :
      {
        "name": "automation",
        "url": "MY_APPLICATION_ENDPOINT"
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the sample work fine for you?

Comment: @LeonNicholls Yes, my endpoints works fine. Problem is that I can't see errors at google console if any while firing the intent call.

Comment: Try reporting the issue using the support form: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/